# cURL not sending content-length

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm trying to get an O-Auth token from the Spotify API but when using cURL on Debian 8 I always get the error message `POST requests require a Content-length header.` while it works on my MacBook.

```
$authString = $spotifyId . ":" . $spotifySecret;
$encodedAuthString = base64_encode($authString);

$spotifyHeaders = array(
    "Authorization: Basic " . $encodedAuthString,
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
);

$spotifyOauthCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($spotifyOauthCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");
curl_setopt($spotifyOauthCurl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($spotifyOauthCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $spotifyHeaders);
curl_setopt($spotifyOauthCurl, POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($spotifyOauthCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// curl_setopt($spotifyOauthCurl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
$result = curl_exec($spotifyOauthCurl);
echo curl_getinfo($spotifyOauthCurl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
```

Adding CURLOPT_VERBOSE as suggested by @hanshenrik returned the following output

```
Trying 35.186.224.25...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to accounts.spotify.com (35.186.224.25) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=SE; L=Stockholm; O=Spotify AB; CN=*.spotify.com
*  start date: May  3 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: May  3 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "accounts.spotify.com" matched certs "*.spotify.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /api/token HTTP/1.1

/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.spotify.com
Accept: */ *
Authorization: Basic ...
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue

* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Content-Length: 1564
< Date: Wed, 26 Jan 2022 17:36:23 GMT
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE: ```$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($spotifyOauthCurl,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
curl_exec($spotifyOauthCurl);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
echo $stderr;
``` and show the verbose log... i find it _very_ hard to believe that setting POSTFIELDS to a string did not make libcurl add a Content-Length header..

Comment: Where is the body being set?

Comment: @hanshenrik unfortunately that outputs nothing all

Comment: @hobbs I tried to set the body before with POSTFIELDS but it didn't change anything about the response by the Spotify API

Comment: @ProfGhost in that case your script is either crashing or running under ob_start(); ... anything in the php error logs?

Comment: @hanshenrik after commenting out CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT I got an output which I added to the question

Comment: @ProfGhost oh dang.. that's another bug btw: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65348 - aaanyway, you cut off too much from the verbose string, you're only showing the headers received, not the headers sent. can you show more/all of the verbose output?

Comment: @hanshenrik thanks for the info, I added the whole output to the question

Comment: @ProfGhost ok... that makes no sense. there's no way the code provided does not send a content-length header (and the log says that no content-length header was sent). the only way i can imagine it happening is if your real code is ```curl_setopt($spotifyOauthCurl, POSTFIELDS, $SomeVariable);``` and $someVariable is null/emptystring =/ what is the real code you use for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS?

Comment: @hanshenrik sadly that is the real code I use and what the Spotify API requires. Somehow I'm a little bit relieved that I'm not the only that thinks this makes no sense

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HTTP%2F1.0+411+Length+Required. That said, have you tried the obvious and set the header manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: you're ignoring the error log, every time you run

```
curl_setopt($spotifyOauthCurl, POSTFIELDS, "grant_type: client_credentials");
```

your errorlog gets a message like

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant POSTFIELDS - assumed 'POSTFIELDS' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /in/S9fsj on line 3
string(10) "POSTFIELDS"
```

Also you're running php 5/7, because in PHP8 this will throw an exception: https://3v4l.org/S9fsj

2: you're ignoring curl_setopt return errors, curl_setopt returns false on errors, which your code is ignoring. an easy way around that would be

```
function ecurl_setopt ( /*resource*/$ch , int $option , /*mixed*/ $value ){
    $ret=curl_setopt($ch,$option,$value);
    if($ret!==true){
        //option should be obvious by stack trace
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'curl_setopt() failed. curl_errno: ' .  curl_errno ($ch) .'. curl_error: '.curl_error($ch) );
    }
}
```

3: it's all caused by a typo! it's supposed to be `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` not just `POSTFIELDS`

Comment: Damn, I was already at the correct line   Good find Hans!

Comment: Thank you very much, seems like days of trying to find made overlook it. I'm still wondering tho why it worked on my MacBook and not on Debian

Comment: You should really turn on error reporting to debug. If you hide all the errors, you leave yourself and the people you ask for a guessing game.

Comment: @ProfGhost a mystery indeed, it definitely should not have worked on your macbook either :o